# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials error -- nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, fetch, aws-api-gateway

I am getting the cors error. Am I missing anything? Below is the code which I have and the error which I am getting.

**App Info**:

Back-end is uploaded on lambda using serverless npm === which created api-gateway.

Mongodb is hosted on aws-ec2 instance .

Front-end/React is hosted on s3 bucket.

Thank you so much!

`Access to fetch at '[node.js api-url, which is hosted on api-gateway/lambda]' from origin '[front-end react-url, which is hosted on aws-s3 bucket]' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'false' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

**Node.js code:**

```
db.initialize();
initAxios(defaults);

const app = express();
if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
  app.server = https.createServer(config.sslOptions, app);
} else {
  app.server = http.createServer(app);
}

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));

app.use(expressSession({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    callback(null, true)
  },
  credentials: true
}




app.use(cors(corsOptions));


// I added the below part so maybe it would work but it didn't :)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
// I added the above part so maybe it would work but it didn't :)

app.use(morgan('combined', {
  stream: logger.stream
}));

app.use(`/api/v${process.env.API_VERSION}`, router);
```

**Front-end React Code:**

```
export async function login(data) {

  return fetch(`[api-url]auth/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    // credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onFail)
}
```

Before it was like this:

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: true,
}));
```

So I converted into:

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your API endpoint is the API Gateway, not the Lambda, so you need to enable CORS on the actual Gateway.

There are multiple ways of doing this, but if you are using Serverless Framework for your deployment, there is a very good tutorial for enabling CORS [here](https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/).

The quick and dirty way is just to add 'cors: true' under 'events: -http:' when you're describing your function endpoint in your serverless.yml.

Example:

```
events:
  - http:
      path: product
      method: post
      cors: true
```

Comment: I just checked it is already enabled :```functions:
  app:
    handler: index.run
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true```

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Are you using cookies or some form of authentication in your request?

Comment: @K Mo No, but to confirm do I check that in nodejs code? but I am using session:

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the
// session.
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Have you added the headers  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' & 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, to your response as suggested in the tutorial linked in my answer?

Comment: I added this: 
```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```